# Undefined function?

Tags: php, function, class, pdo

I'm getting an error telling me that I have called an undefined function, but I know the function is defined in the include. Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: BeerEditor is a class. You need to instantiate the class then call the method on that instance.

Comment: @Fred-ii- two different problems man. read them through next time.

Comment: I did and that's why I'm wondering why you accepted the answer that was given. Plus, you're not interacting with the person who's given you one below, knowing if it's even working or not.

Comment: I selected an answer on the last one. Also while the errors look similar at first glance, one is an undefined variable, and the other is an undefined function.

Comment: Vote has been retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the BeerEditor class as i can understand from your code so you can fix it by something like this

```
$beer_editor = new BeerEditor($dbconn);
$beer_editor->addBeer($new_beer);
```

Comment: Yes! But of course it only led to another error :/ if you'd like to help I would love your input!